# Jackson,проблема с парсингом

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Есть такой Json

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "make": "[{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Replay\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Replica\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Vianor\"},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Kosei\"},{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"Invader\"},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"MANSORY\"},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"RAYS\"},{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"VISSOL\"}]"
```

Мои Pojo-классы выглядят следующим образом.

```
public class Pojo_Params {
private Boolean success;
private String data;
private List<Pojo_Params_Data> make;

public Boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}


public List<Pojo_Params_Data> getMake() {
    return make;
}

public void setMake(List<Pojo_Params_Data> make) {
    this.make = make;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(make.toArray());
}
```

и

```
public class Pojo_Params_Data {
private String id,name;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + "="+ id;
}
```

"make" - это ведь список? Выдает такую ошибку  `W/System.err: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неверно сформированы классы. 
make - не список, а строка.

Вот верный вариант:

```
public class MyPojo
{
    private Data data;

    private String success;

    public Data getData ()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData (Data data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getSuccess ()
    {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess (String success)
    {
        this.success = success;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [data = "+data+", success = "+success+"]";
    }
}



public class Data
{
    private String make;

    public String getMake ()
    {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake (String make)
    {
        this.make = make;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [make = "+make+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.[] сбили с толку